# Upgrade Gnome 3.4 to 3.8 in debian 7

Tags: debian, gnome, upgrade, gnome-shell

I need to upgrade gnome 3.4 to 3.8 in debian7 (with gnome-classic). How?

Comment: What have you tried? Downloading the package from gnome.org? [Apt pinning](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html)? [Google](https://www.google.fr/search?&q=debian+gnome+3.8)?

Comment: i do not try any things but i still asking : is it possible to upgrade   3,4 to 3,8 under debian7?

Comment: Yes, well, please go try some things first and come back if you have specific problems. Yes, it is possible, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run GNOME 3.8 now on Debian, the easiest option at the moment is upgrading your installation to either Jessie (currently Debian Testing) and/or Sid (Debian Unstable). Afterwards, you will need some packages from Experimental, since not all 3.8 packages are available on Sid yet (e.g. `gnome-shell`) [due to some transitions](http://lists.debian.org/debian-gtk-gnome/2013/05/msg00005.html).